# How can I complete animating these divs diagonally?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have already gotten the blue and red divs to move diagonal and replace eachother. I know need the green and pink divs to do the same using a similar function to the others.

Unsure with the position of the div being both 0 and 350 for both of those divs

i need to the green div to move to where the pink

```js
function click_move() {
  myMove();
  myMove2();
  myMove3();
  myMove4(); 
}


function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function myMove2() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate2");   
  var pos = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame2, 5);
  function frame2() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos  + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button{
 position:fixed;
  left: 500px;
  top:  100px;}

#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed; 
  background: yellow;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;  
  background-color: red;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}

#animate2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;  
  background-color: blue;
  top:350px;
  left:350px;
}

#animate3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;  
  background-color: green;
  top: 0px;
  left:350px;
}

#animate4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;  
  background-color: pink;
  top: 350px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>
<button onclick="click_move()">Click Me</button>
</p> 
<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
<div id ="animate2"></div>
<div id ="animate3"></div>
<div id ="animate4"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

div is and the pink div to move to where the green div is

Answer (score 0):

i got it to work on my own. i did a long way of breaking up the function

```js
function click_move() {
  myMove();
  myMove2();
  myMove3();
  myMove4(); 
  myMove5();
  myMove6();
}


function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function myMove2() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate2");   
  var pos = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame2, 5);
  function frame2() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos  + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function myMove3() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate3");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame3, 5);
  function frame3() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}

function myMove4() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate3");   
  var pos = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame3, 5);
  function frame3() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}

function myMove5() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate4");   
  var pos = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame4, 5);
  function frame4() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}

function myMove6() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate4");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame4, 5);
  function frame4() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button{
 position:fixed;
  left: 500px;
  top:  500px;}

#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed; 
  background: yellow;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;  
  background-color: blue;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}

#animate2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;  
  background-color: pink;
  top:350px;
  left:350px;
}

#animate3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;  
  background-color: red;
  top: 0px;
  left:350px;
}

#animate4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;  
  background-color: green;
  top: 350px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>
<button onclick="click_move()">Click Me</button>
</p> 
<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
<div id ="animate2"></div>
<div id ="animate3"></div>
<div id ="animate4"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is not so different! for the first two functions all you need is a 'pos' variable because for red and blue, left and top are equal during the animation so you can move them with only one variable that stands for both left and top like 'pos'!
But for the other two divs left and top are not equal so you have to specify them separately!

like this:

```
function myMove3() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate3");   
  var left = 350;
  var top = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame3, 5);
  function frame3() {
    if (left == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      left--; 
      top++;
      elem.style.top = top + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = left  + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function myMove4() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate4");   
  var left = 0;
  var top = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame4, 5);
  function frame4() {
    if (left == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      left++; 
      top--;
      elem.style.top = top + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = left  + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using HTML-Elements with styling instead of a [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API), I would recommend using CSS and its [`transition`-property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) for interpolating between the two positions.

The advantages of using CSS instead of JS for this are:

1. CSS has a simple property to achieve exactly what you want
2. CSS tries to create as many frames with as little lags as possible
3. CSS uses less RAM as JS (as `transition` is basically made for this)
4. It can be toggled half-way through as well!
5. Frees up callstack of JS, allowing other calls to be executed
6. Very simple JS!

To make life easier, I also used [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to define the size of the squares you want to move, resolving them using `var()` when using them.
I named mine `--span-size`.

Since we want to place the squares in the corners of their parent, we can simply calculate the wanted positions:
**Note** that the origin of an HTML-Element is its top-left corner.

- Top-left: `top: 0%` `left: 0%`
- Top-right: `top: 0%` `right: calc(100% - var(--span-size))`
- Bottom-left: `top: calc(100% - var(--span-size))` `left: 0%`
- Bottom-right: `top: calc(100% - var(--span-size))` `right: calc(100% - var(--span-size))`

We simply have to use the correct selectors, and can toggle between the two states by toggling a class of their parent (I used `.toggled`).
And in the CSS, we simply define the start- and end-values we want, and the transition-duration it should take.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.classList.toggle('toggled');
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
span {
  --span-size: 32px;
  
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--span-size);
  height: var(--span-size);
  transition: 1s linear;
}

#s1 {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  background: red;
}
#s2 {
  top: 0%;
  left: calc(100% - var(--span-size));
  background: green;
}
#s3 {
  top: calc(100% - var(--span-size));
  left: 0%;
  background: blue;
}
#s4 {
  top: calc(100% - var(--span-size));
  left: calc(100% - var(--span-size));
  background: pink;
}

div.toggled #s1 {
  top: calc(100% - var(--span-size));
  left: calc(100% - var(--span-size));
}
div.toggled #s2 {
  top: calc(100% - var(--span-size));
  left: 0%;
}
div.toggled #s3 {
  top: 0%;
  left: calc(100% - var(--span-size));
}
div.toggled #s4 {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="s1"></span> <!-- 'sX' for 'span-ID', to simplify selecting them -->
  <span id="s2"></span>
  <span id="s3"></span>
  <span id="s4"></span>
</div>
<button>Toggle state!</button>
```